# A criterion for a subset $M\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k$ to be a $C^r$-manifold

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Prove the following theorem.

Fix $r\in \{0\}\cup\{\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\infty\}$. A subset $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ is a $C^r$-manifolf (without boundry) of dimension $m$ if and only if for all points $c \in M$ there exists

a. an open neighborhood $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ of $c$

b. an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$

c. $C^r$ diffeomorphism $U \xleftarrow {\xrightarrow{\phi}}_{\psi} V\cap M$

### My attempt:

By definition we know that   subset $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ is a $C^r$-manifolf (without boundry) of dimension $m$ if and only if for all points $c \in M$ there exists an open neighborhood $U \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, an open set $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ with a $C^r$ diffeomorphism $\phi:U \rightarrow V$ such that $\phi(U \cap M) = V \cap (\mathbb{R}^m \times \{0\})$ with inverse $\psi:V \rightarrow U$.

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The notation $\{0\} \cup \{\mathbb{N} \} \cup \{\infty\}$ means something different from what you mean. This set would have three elements namely, $0$, $\infty$ and the set of all natural numbers. What you mean is  $\{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}  \cup \{\infty\}$

Comment: Something is missing in condition c. What properties does the $C^r$-diffeomorphism have?